# Responsive Design with @media in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

I tried to make my website responsive but it does not work.
With @media i want to define different areas but with my code nothing chances.

```
    @media (max-width: 1400px) {
    #football {
        left: 70%;
        top: 0%;
    }
    
    #skiing {
        left: 70%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    
    #volleyball {
        left: 70%;
        top: 60%;
    }
    
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Your `@media` rule is missing the closing curly bracket (`}`).

Comment: Just forgot to copy

Comment: Are you sure those tags are ID and not classes? If class use . instead of #.  Also I'd probably added a position to each of those elements e.g. position:relative or position: absolute (depending on your requirement)

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

Comment: The tags are IDs and i have defined the position for all of them

Comment: ```@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) { ...// rest of your code }```

Comment: You may need to set the position (`position: relative | absolute`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to put the media query at the **end** of your code. Also don't forget to add this meta tag to the head element in html file.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale= 1.0">
```

By the way try editing query like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    #football {
        left: 70%;
        top: 0%;
    }
    
    #skiing {
        left: 70%;
        top: 30%;
    }
    
    #volleyball {
        left: 70%;
        top: 60%;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the meta tag embedded inside `<head>`:

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale= 1.0">
```

css:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1400px){

/* your code */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to define the type

```
@media all and (max-width: 1400px){
     your code
}
```

and make sure to add the meta tag in the head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale= 1.0">
```